# How to manage `state` nonce auth0 authorization code grant flow?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, auth0

My application consists of a client side html/javascript, a web server, and an API (a "regular web app", as auth0 calls it). On the [Authorization Code Grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant) doc page on Auth0, it says to create a URL like this:

```
https://ygctest.auth0.com/authorize?
    audience=YOUR_API_AUDIENCE&
    scope=YOUR_SCOPE&
    response_type=code&
    client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&
    redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP/callback&
    state=YOUR_OPAQUE_VALUE
```

The doc says the state (apparently a nonce to prevent CSRF) returned from the auth0 server via query parameter to `/callback` needs to be compared to the originally generated state.

My question is: Where should the "state" variable be generated? And, does the state variable need to be verified on the client, server, or both?

Should I generate it on the server and pass it to the client somehow? If so, is it better to do it as a cookie, or can I just generate the entire URL serverside and stick it in the html?

If the state variable should be generated on the client side, how should the server know what the client thinks the state is? The browser is redirected from the login page to `/callback` (in the example), so the client doesn't have a chance to check the state. Should the client set a cookie so that the `GET` to `/callback` includes the state?

Comment: Hi. Did my answer help you? Please leave comments if still unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the session state on the server-side, store its value in session (encrypted cookie or server-side storage cache (eg. Redis). Then during the code authorization grant flow, check its value as a first action in your callback. Some libraries might handle the check for you, or else you will have to do the ceremony of pulling the state value explicitly out of session storage in your code, and comparing that explicitly against the value of state that was returned to your callback endpoint.

If you are using Auth0 Hosted Login Page, and making a call to `authorize` endpoint, then you can just do it all server-side - see [here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-regular-webapp-login-with-sso-and-api/blob/master/routes/index.js#L24). If you need to render a form on UI with state value then your Controller can pass the value of your state to the view layer as a value that gets interpolated. The key takeaway is that it is recommended to generate the value server-side, store it in secured session storage, and do the comparison server-side (in the callback) for code authorization grant flow (regular web app).